# Bootstrap: affix navigation blocking scroll-to section title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, scrollto

I have a side scrolling navigation with scroll spy (that I grabbed from bootstrap) and everything is working fine except that the section titles are being covered by the affixed navigation when scrolled to.

I have an offset of 75 in scroll-spy.js, but I am not sure how to push the content down or tell the scrolling to focus right above the actual title of each section so they aren't covered up.

You can see what I am talking about at "url has been removed"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add top padding to the `<section>` elements that your navigation links are targeting.

In your case, you can just add this to your style sheet:

```
section { padding-top: 30px; }
```