# Bootstrap link to section - title hidden by navbar-fixed-top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble with using section ref links with bootstrap. I have a navbar which is fixed to the top of the page, and then some section navigation in a span3 as
    
The items here link to  tags in the span9. I have padded the body by 60px so that the page content sits below the fixed navbar, but when I use the section links, the relevant  is aligned to the very top of the page, underneath the navbar - this means the title becomes hidden.

I have had a look at [Bootstrap: affix navigation blocking scroll-to section title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184409/bootstrap-affix-navigation-blocking-scroll-to-section-title)
 but this pads the sections themselves, which alters the spacing. I would like to keep the spacing of the page as is default with Bootstrap.

How can I stop the content in the span9 from disappearing under the navbar when I use the section links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `padding` to the top of the element, and then a negative `margin`. You'll just need to adjust the value for both (in this case `15px`) depending on the height of your navbar, and if it is fixed even on mobile devices, etc.

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/h4Ym9/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#description1">Description 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#description2">Description 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#description3">Description 3</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#description4">Description 4</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="description1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="content-bubble drop-shadow curved">
                 <h2 class="heading">Product Description 1</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p class="last">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-bubble-triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="description2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="content-bubble drop-shadow curved">
                 <h2 class="heading">Product Description </h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p class="last">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-bubble-triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="description3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="content-bubble drop-shadow curved">
                 <h2 class="heading">Product Description 3</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p class="last">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-bubble-triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="description4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="content-bubble drop-shadow curved">
                 <h2 class="heading">Product Description 4</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p class="last">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-bubble-triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-inner{
    min-height:95px;
}
section {
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```